# Evaluating $\iint_R|x+|y||\, d(x,y)$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to determine the following integral

$$\iint_{R} |x+|y||\, dx\,dy\qquad ;R=[-1, 1]\times[-1, 1].$$
I had two ideas to address this problem, clearly considering integrating by iteration. The first is the following:

$$\begin{align*}\iint_{R} |x+|y||\, dx\,dy &=\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\int_{-1}^{1} |x+|y||\,dx\right)\,dy\\
&=\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\int_{-1}^{0} |x+|y||\,dx + \int_{0}^{1} |x+|y||\,dx\right)\,dy.\end{align*}$$

By splitting that integral in two, according to the integration intervals at $[-1, 0]$, I could take $-x-∣y∣$ and, at $[0, 1]$, I could take $x+∣y∣$. I could then find those integrals and do the other two possible cases for $∣y∣$. This argument doesn't quite convince me I'm not sure about it.

My other idea is to divide that integral in 4 cases and at the end add them all up, these would be:

1. when $|x+|y||=x+|y|$ and

- $|y|=-y$
- $|y|=y$

2. when $|x+|y||=-x-|y|$ and

- $|y|=-y$
- $|y|=y$

Now, this last strategy makes each integral worth zero and, in the long run, the initial double integral has a value of zero. Is that correct? any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem clearly is the absolute value, find a way to eliminate it and you are done:
$$\begin{align*}\iint_R|x+|y||\,d(x,y)&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1|x+|y||\,dx\,dy\\
&= \int_{-1}^0\int_{-1}^1|x-y|\,dx\,dy+\int_{0}^1\int_{-1}^1|x+y|\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_{-1}^0\left(\int_{-1}^yy-x\,dx+\int_{y}^1x-y\,dx\right)\,dy+\int_{0}^1\left(\int_{-1}^{-y}-x-y\,dx+\int_{-y}^1x+y\,dx\right)\,dy.\end{align*}$$

You should be able to take it from here.